# Show all stored procedures currently running

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

In MySQL, I'm trying to find away to check if a stored procedure is currently executing. Is there a command/query I can run that reveals this information?

I looked at the following commands with no success:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;

SELECT * FROM information_schema.routines WHERE routine_name = 'sp_name';

SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS;
```

Comment: I'm not sure but i think that `show processlist` should show it. If it's not there, then it isn't.

Comment: Show processlist shows the commands that are executed in the stored procedure. It does not show the procedure name itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to accomplish this that I can think of is to watch the general query log, or build logging / statistics into your application.

If you need to know this information for instrumentation, I would suggest taking a look at the slow query log and various tools to parse its data (pt_query_digest, anemometer, etc)